# How do I pass DB field value to radio button using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Reading the DB using ajax, I have the following:

```
$('#fetch').click(function(){
    var nameid = parseInt($('#names').val());
    $.ajax({
        url       : "ws.php",
        type      : "POST",
        datatype  : "JSON",
        data      : {                           
                        editvalues  : 1,
                        id          : nameid
                    },
        success:function(show){
            $('#cr').val(show.creditrated);
        }
    });
});
```

And I'm trying to pass the value if `creditrated` to radio buttons using `cr`:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
<?php if($row[11] == "Y") { ?>
    <input type="radio" id="cr" value="Y" checked><strong>Yes</strong>
    <input type="radio" style="margin-left: 8px" id="cr"  value="N"><strong>No</strong>
    <?php } elseif($row[11] == "N") { ?>
    <input type="radio" id="cr" value="Y"><strong>Yes</strong>
    <input type="radio" style="margin-left: 8px" id="cr"  value="N" checked><strong>No</strong>
<?php } else { ?>
    <input type="radio" id="cr" value="Y"><strong>Yes</strong>
    <input type="radio" style="margin-left: 8px" id="cr"  value="N"><strong>No</strong>
<?php } ?>
    <span class="error" style="color: red"> <?php echo $crErr;?></span>
```

`$row[11]` holds the value `"Y"` or `"N"`.

I know I have these radio buttons tagged wrongly, but i don't know how to do it the right way. Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Btw, I have 15 other fields (not shown in the ajax) that are all loading properly. This is the only one giving me a problem.

Comment: What is the value that you get in `show.creditrated` ?

Comment: `id` is an unique identifier, for access the `input` fields you should use `name` tag.

Comment: Arkantos: I get either a Y or an N, depending on what's in the db.

Comment: Gonzalo: I've tried it both ways: using `id = "cr"` and `name = "cr"`. Both are failing.

Comment: You can select the radio button by setting `checked` property to `true` like this `$('#cr').prop('checked', true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following changes

```
$('#fetch').click(function(){
    var nameid = parseInt($('#names').val());
    $.ajax({
        url       : "ws.php",
        type      : "POST",
        datatype  : "JSON",
        data      : {                           
                        editvalues  : 1,
                        id          : nameid
                    },
        success:function(show){
            if(show.creditrated == "Y") {
                $("#cr_Y").prop("checked", true);
                $("#cr_N").prop("checked", false);
            }
            else {
                $("#cr_Y").prop("checked", false);
                $("#cr_N").prop("checked", true);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And add name property to radio buttons linked together...

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="radio" name="radioSet" id="cr_Y" value="Y"><strong>Yes</strong>
    <input type="radio" name="radioSet" style="margin-left: 8px" id="cr_N"  value="N"><strong>No</strong>
    <span class="error" style="color: red" id="crErr"></span>
```

Comment: Abhash Upadhyaya: That did the trick. I'm only a week into using JQuery and really appreciate your insight. Thank you so much.